# User JVM parameter in log4j2 configuration

Tags: java, config, log4j2, jvm-arguments

I have an RollingFile Appender defined in my log4j2.xml.

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/logs/app.log"
            filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %-5p - %m - [%l]%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
</RollingFile>
```

What I want to do is to pass this parameter to the JVM at startup:

```
-Dapp_home=/home/admin/server
```

The [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#JmxRuntimeInputArgumentsLookup) is pretty straight forward. And from what I understand it should work like this:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${jvmrunargs:app_home}/logs/app.log"
```

But it doesn't. I verified that it is working in general by using the absolut path.

In an other application where I use log4j (1.x) it works like this:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${app_home}/logs/app.log
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Take a look at the [System Properties Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#SystemPropertiesLookup) section of the documentation. If you define a variable as system property using `-D` like this:

```
-Dapp_home=/home/admin/server
```

use

```
${sys:app_home}
```

in your Log4j 2 configuration to access it.

Comment: Your answer is better written, but the content/answer is the same. I will delete mine. There is an edit button for a reason, use it instead of posting a duplicate.

Comment: I never used the edit button for anything else than code formatting. It feels like tampering with someone else's property. But I guess that is the way Stackoverflow is supposed to work. I'll remember it next time. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Same answer, same result! It works! :) Thank you both!